# Polymorphic class in Python that returns an instance of another class

Tags: python, class, constructor, polymorphism

I have class container that transmute itself into another class.

For example I have some types such as `MyFloat` `MyStr` or `MyInt` that offer  additional methods or attributes. I would like to encapsulate the decision to build any of these types into another class:

My first attempt was to write this:

```
class MyFloat(float):
    def foo_float():
        pass

class MyStr(str):
    def foo_str():
        pass

class MyInt(int):
    def foo_int():
        pass

# Does not work
class Polymorph(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, float):
            self = MyFloat(value)         
        elif isinstance(value, int):
            self = MyInt(value)
        elif isinstance(value, str):
            self = MyStr(value)
        else:
            raise TypeError, 'Unknown type'
```

Unfortunately I did not get the expected instance at the end:

```
>>> a = Polymorph(42.42) # Should get an instance of MyFloat
>>> type(a)
__main.MyFloat
```

I then tried to use `__new__` instead

```
class Polymorph(object):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        if isinstance(value, float):
            return super(MyFloat, cls).__new__(cls, value)
        elif isinstance(value, int):
            return super(MyInt, cls).__new__(cls, value)
        elif isinstance(value, str):
            return super(MyStr, cls).__new__(cls, value)
        else:
            raise TypeError, 'Unknown type'
```

But this time I get a `TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found this solution that works. However, I don't know is it is Pythonic Acceptable to do this.

```
class Polymorph(object):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        if isinstance(value, float):
            return MyFloat(value)
        elif isinstance(value, int):
            return MyInt(value)
        elif isinstance(value, str):
            return MyStr(value)
        else:
            raise TypeError, 'Unknown type'
```

Comment: I'd say it is not always python-way. Using underscore-methods is kind of allowed hacking. You hide some logic, but [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says: `Explicit is better than implicit.`.  If you don't mind, I think it would be better to use factory function instead of class: `def get_myclass(value)`